# Machine not booting up

Tags: boot

My system is not booting up past the Ubintu spinning wheel. I get the following message come up just before the login screen:

/dev/sda3: clean, 200322/45760511 files, 183007477/183011505 clean

Is there anything I can  do or is it a OS reinstall?

Comment: Is the hard drive still being read?  If so, it means the computer is still doing "something" and hasn't frozen.  The message shown is just reporting on the progress of a disk check.  If you have multiple hard disks, then it could be checking the next one and it's just taking a long time (i.e., because the hard disk is large or there are some errors encountered).  How long did you wait?

Comment: Can you try to switch to another TTY (virtual terminal) with `ctrl + alt + f4`? Sometimes, the OS is stuck while loading the display manager.

Comment: What was the last thing you did on you pc?

Comment: /dev/sda3: clean, 200322/45760511 files, 183007477/183011505 clean. Is not an error it's confirming that you system is clean.

Comment: Thanks all. Previously I left it for about 30 minutes and nothing changed. Will try a little bit longer this time.

Comment: I tried ctrl alt + F4 and nothing. The last time I was using the PC I was looking at Bleachclean but not sure if I did anything to corrupt.

Comment: I am wondering if a bootloader will help as it is getting stuck at this point